Impresion de los resultados
tengo un un problema, lo que pasa es que estoy realizando un codigo en ensamblador para realizar las 4 operaciones basicas(Suma, resta, multiplicacion y division), pero al momento de realizar la impresion, unicamente toma la primera cifra de los dos numeros pero cuando ya son numeros por asi decirlo diferentes por ejemplo 20 y 12, 24 y 12 da resultados que ni al caso, les proporciono el codigo, espero que podrian ayudarme por favor:
.model small
.stack
.data
n1 db 0
n2 db 0
r db 0
msg1 db 10,13,7,'Suma: ','$'
msg2 db 10,13,7,'Resta: ','$'
msg3 db 10,13,7,'Mult: ','$'
msg4 db 10,13,7,'Div: ','$'
msg0 db 10,13,7,'Ingresa un numero de dos cifras: ','$'

.code
main proc far
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

call LeerNumero
mov n1, al

call LeerNumero
mov n2, al

; Suma
mov al, n1
add al, n2
mov r, al
lea dx, msg1
call ImprimirResultado

; Resta
mov al, n1
sub al, n2
mov r, al
lea dx, msg2
call ImprimirResultado

; Multiplicacion
mov al, n1
mov bl, n2
mul bl
mov r, al
lea dx, msg3
call ImprimirResultado

; Division
xor ax, ax
mov bl, n2
mov al, n1
div bl
mov r, al
lea dx, msg4
call ImprimirResultado

mov ah, 4Ch
int 21h
main endp

LeerNumero proc
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg0
int 21h

; Leer primer dígito
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h
mov ah, 0
mov bl, al

; Leer segundo dígito
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al, 30h

; Combinar los dígitos
mov ah, 0Ah
mul ah
add al, bl
ret
LeerNumero endp

ImprimirResultado proc
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov al, r
AAM
mov bx, ax
mov ah, 02h
mov dl, bh
add dl, 30h
int 21h

mov ah, 02h
mov dl, bl
add dl, 30h
int 21h
ret
ImprimirResultado endp

end main

Las imagenes las publico en google drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kqhaD-tNUrOwks3vSSsTNBQHHeOKRMa_/view?usp=drive_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ohejsmqc9EZEqJ49RFJxHn7RC9i5Xe7I/view?usp=drive_link

Pasa el código de las funciones.

Encontré este repositorio ayer, puede que te dé una idea en lo que estás fallando. https://github.com/Assembly-Fundation/Basics-Tutorials-MASM-x64-for-Visual-Studio.git
